# matlab have no response after calling a mex function many times

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

I'm hoping someone can help me with a problem I'm having with some mex code I've written.
    After calling the same mex function many times, the matlab will have no response. I post the code here:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], /* Output variables */
        int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) /* Input variables */
{
    const char *fieldnames[3]; //This will hold field names.
    fieldnames[0] = (char*)mxMalloc(20);
    fieldnames[0] = "mean";

    plhs[0] = mxCreateCellMatrix(11, 1);
    mxArray *cells = plhs[0];

    mxArray *treeNodeMean;
    double *mean;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        mxArray* treeNode  = mxCreateStructMatrix(1,1,1,fieldnames);
        mxSetCell(cells, i , treeNode);//set treeNode to tree

        //initialize
        treeNodeMean  = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(2,58, mxREAL);

        //set values
        mean = mxGetPr(treeNodeMean);

        for(int j = 0; j<=(58*2);j++) {
            mean[j] = (double)j;
        }

        //set treeNode
        mxSetFieldByNumber(treeNode,0,0, treeNodeMean);//(pointer,index,fieldNumber,value)
    }
    return;
}
```

---

1. When I call the mex function in the command window as fllow:

---

> > for i = 1:100
> >
> > A = createTrees;
> >
> > end

---

Matlab not responding after long runing.

2. If I delete the code:

---

```
for(int j = 0; j<=(58*2);j++) {
    mean[j] = (double)j;
}
```

---

from the mex function, the case of “Matlab not responding after long runing.” will disappear.
So, How can I solve the "No response" problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: it is not clear what your problems is. what par of the code raises erros? can you extract working code from the loop to new functions?

Comment: Make a second version without the mex-specific stuff (normal allocations with `malloc` for example. Recommend dropping the C++ tag here, by the way) and test out the logic without matlab. You'll have a much easier time debugging in a standard C IDE's debugger. Once you know the logic is solid, then re-mexify. You may also be able to attach your IDE's debugger to matlab and catch the crash with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop in question is accessing the array out of bounds. C-style indexing goes from `0` to `N-1` instead of `1` to `N` (as in MATLAB), so your loop termination condition should be `j<(58*2)` instead of `<=`.

You may also want to double-check the loop termination condition for your outer loop (over `i`), because that is only looping over 10 elements despite you allocating memory for 11.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are cautious!